# What are the best spots for chain fishing in Pokémon x

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have read things like "in a corner" but I don't know what "corner" means, where I can find them, or what kind of corners they are. Can I have some help/pictures of the best corners? Because I don't know what they mean, I am ok with the Pokémon with the suction cups ability like they said.

Comment: This is the fourth account you've created.  If you're sticking around, I'd highly recommend registering and taking our [tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour).  You'll learn a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are more likely to encounter pokemon while fishing in areas containing rocks. As a notifier your background, in battle, will contain images of those rocks, and I believe, how many rocks. I prefer chaining West Kalos shore, but you'll mostly encounter, (playing y) shellder and skrelp.